# MySQL SQL order join for multiple records

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have 2 tables:

1. Customers
2. Files

How do I do a join to show the latest record, i.e by created_on DESC

e.g

```
SELECT customers.name, files.last_file_submission
```

if I have:

```
customer A
 - File 1, created_on 10-10-2012
 - File 2, created_on 11-10-2012
```

and I want to return a single line for each customer that has:

```
customer A, 11-10-2012
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per file:

```
SELECT c.name, f.submit_date
FROM files f, customers c
WHERE f.submitter = c.id
ORDER BY f.submit_date DESC
```

Per user:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.name, MAX(f.submit_date)
FROM files f, customers c
WHERE f.submitter = c.id
ORDER BY MAX(f.submit_date) DESC
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: I should add it should return a list of all customer, LIMIT 1 will only return the first customer?

Comment: You need a `GROUP BY customers.PK`

Answer (score 0):

It will bring all the Customer and their latest file date regardless if the customer has any record of file or not.

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer.id, customer.name, MAX(file.submit_date)
FROM customer LEFT JOIN file ON customer.id = file.submitter
GROUP BY customer.id, customer.name
```

You can change `LEFT` with `INNER` to restrict the join only between those customer who have the reference on file table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your right as well wish I could pick both